# How do I squeeze a $\theta(t)$ and $\varphi(t)$ out of this?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

[image]

A ball attached to a fixed-length massless rod [swings about](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_pendulum) under gravity. Mathematically:

$$L=T-U=\frac{MR^2}{2}(\sin^2(\theta)\dot{\varphi}^2+\dot{\theta}^2)+MgR \cos(\theta)$$

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\theta}}\right)=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta}$$
$$MR^2 \ddot{\theta}=MR^2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\dot{\varphi}^2-MgR \sin(\theta)$$
$$MR^2 \ddot{\theta}=\frac{MR^2}{2}\sin(2\theta)\dot{\varphi}^2-MgR \sin(\theta)\tag{1}$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\varphi}}\right)=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \varphi}$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}(MR^2 \sin^2(\theta) \dot{\varphi})=0$$
$$MR^2( \sin^2(\theta) \ddot{\varphi}+2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) \dot{\varphi}\dot{\theta})=0$$
$$MR^2( \sin^2(\theta) \ddot{\varphi}+\sin(2\theta) \dot{\varphi}\dot{\theta})=0\tag{2}.$$

Any ideas as to the domestication of these equations? Any approximative tricks?

**Edit:** I forget that it's useful if I post some of my own insights to aid answerers

1. $\sin(\theta)=\theta+o(\theta^3)$, so approximate $\sin(\theta) \approx \theta$
2. For cosine, it's not so easy, because $cos(\theta)=1+o(\theta^2)$ doesn't hold for as long, so perhaps $cos(\theta) \approx 1-\frac{1}{2}\theta^2$ *could* work, but there's enough trouble already with the equations being nonlinear before adding a squared term.

Comment: Those look like equations of motion to me. Are you looking for a closed-form solution?

Comment: Edited title: I wondered whether explicit $\theta$ and $\varphi$ would be found as functions of $t$.

Comment: Your equation is invariant under translation of $t$ and $\phi$. You will get two constant of motions, one for the "angular momentum" of $\phi$ and one for energy. At the end, you can express $t$ as inverse function of some integral over $\theta$. In similar problem without the $\phi$ term, I think $\theta(t)$ can be expressed in terms of elliptic functions but I'm not 100% sure. Hope this helps.

Comment: If you're assuming $\theta\ll1$, then this is just the motion of a particle in a $2$D plane under a centripetal force proportional to $\theta$, which has a classical closed-form solution as an ellipse.

Comment: Hmm.. the physics of the equation is wrong. If the $\dot{\varphi}^2$ term really represent kinetic energy associated with motion in $\varphi$ direction, then the coefficient in front of it should be $\sin(\theta)^2$, not $\sin(\theta)$.

Comment: @achillehui Seems so. I guess $R$ in $\frac{MR}{2}$ should be squared as well?

Comment: @5PM: It should. If the equation is changed, the problem become the standard [spherical pendulum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_pendulum) problem. $t$ and $\varphi$ will be related to $\theta$ through elliptic integrals of $1^{st}$ and $3^{rd}$ kind.

Comment: @achillehui Thank you, that was an idiotic mistake of mine. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no closed form solution for this, unless you assume $\theta \ll1$. In that case you get from the second equation that:
$$\theta\dot{\phi}=C$$
This really doesn't help you unless you make some further assumptions, namely that either $\dot{\phi}$ or $\dot{\theta}$ are equal to 0. I've [seen solutions](http://people.rit.edu/vwlsps/IntermediateMechanics2/Ch%2010.pdf) that try to perturb the system around one of these assumptions and then use a Taylor series to get an approximate solution.

As one of my physics professors told us:

> All problems that can be solved exactly will be taught to you in your undergraduate degree. From then on, it's all approximations.